# Making a local dataset globally accessible

Tags: r, read.csv

I am not sure if I am even asking the right question, but I am relatively new to R and R studio and for a project I was assigned to use a novel dataset to demonstrate every R function I've learned in the course (-_-).. The problem is, the only datasets we have worked with thus far have been handed to us, and since this assignment requires use of a *novel* dataset, I don't know how to make it accessible to the grader if the chunk I'm handing in uses read.csv and looks for the file where it exists on my own device. I have tried to look up this question but I can only find information on local vs global variables but not an entire dataset.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could save the dataset (or any other R object) with 'saveRDS()', and then share it by email or through a cloud service.

Comment: You could also save all of your assignment work in an RStudio project and save that workspace with the novel data frame already loaded (from the .RData file). When the grader opens the project everything will be there.

Comment: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/tutorial-powerful-packages-imputing-missing-values/

Answer (score 2):

If the dataset is not too large use dput to turn it into R code and then just include that code at the top of your script.  For example,

```
dput(BOD)
## structure(list(Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7), demand = c(8.3, 10.3, 
## 19, 16, 15.6, 19.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
## -6L), reference = "A1.4, p. 270")
```

so just put this at the top of the script:

```
# generated from dput(BOD)
BOD <- structure(list(Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7), demand = c(8.3, 10.3, 
  19, 16, 15.6, 19.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -6L), reference = "A1.4, p. 270")
```

Comment: Thank you! Sadly the dataset is 674 observations, is that too large? Hahaha (I'm only kind of kidding).

Comment: Since you are only using it to illustrate some R functions perhaps it is sufficient just to use the first 10 or 20 rows: dput(head(DF, 10))

Comment: Great point, thank you I will give it a shot :)